# Downloaded and installed Anaconda (Individual Edition), but Anaconda Navigator won't open

Tags: python, anaconda

As the title suggests, I downloaded and installed Anaconda (Python 3.8) | Individual Edition, and I get this _conda.exe app, but Anaconda Navigator itself isn't opening up. Even when I try to search Anadconda Prompt, it's not showing in my search bar.

When I open _conda.exe, I get some sort of menu (picture 2) and then it closes. Am I missing something?

[The folder location I chose for installation, and what came with it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sWwG.jpg)

[When opening the _conda.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJSXW.jpg)